# Solving $\frac{\mathrm dx(t)}{\mathrm dt}=\lambda x(t)+f(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a doubt about ordinary-differential-equations.

Here is the equation: $\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=\lambda x(t)+f(t)$.

I don't know why the solution is $x(t)=e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+\int^t_{t_0}e^{\lambda(t-\tau)}f(\tau)d\tau$.

Please help me! Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Take the derivative of your expression for $x(t)$ and show that it satisfies the differential equation.

Comment: @SolubleFish, It's the derivative that $x'(t)=\lambda e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+f(t)$. But that is different from the diferential equation. If the derivate is wrong, please tell me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just solve the ODE using the integrating factor $e^{- \lambda t}$.

Comment: The derivative is wrong because of the $t$ in the exponential factor in the integral.

Comment: Further to @SolubleFish’s comment, I would recommend that you look over the [Liebniz integral rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) carefully.

Comment: Are you unsure *how to arrive at that solution*, or unsure as to *how to verify this solution satisfies the equation*?

Comment: @user170231 former

Comment: @SolubleFish  Thanks for you corrections, i can derive that $\begin{align}x'(t)&=\lambda e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+f(t)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}e^{\lambda(t-\tau)}f(\tau)d\tau\\&=\lambda e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+f(t)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\lambda e^{\lambda(t-\tau)}f(\tau)d\tau\\&=\lambda e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+f(t)-\int_{t_0}^{t}f(\tau)d(e^{\lambda(t-\tau)})\\&=\lambda e^{\lambda(t-t_0)}x(t_0)+f(t)+f(\tau)e^{\lambda(t-\tau)}|_t^{t_0}+\int_{t_0}^te^{\lambda(t-\tau)}d(f(\tau))\end{align}$

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Thank you!

Comment: In the second line, you can already recognize $\lambda x(t) + f(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be skimming over some details. Linear equations are easy solve. When you arrive at

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left[e^{-\lambda t}x(t)\right]=e^{-\lambda t}f(t)$$

the next step is to integrate both sides, which is a job for the fundamental of calculus:

$$e^{-\lambda t}x(t)-e^{-\lambda t_0}x(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^t e^{-\lambda\tau}f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$$

To be a bit clearer, let $g(t)=e^{-\lambda t}f(t)$. The FTC says that if $G(t)$ is an antiderivative of $g(t)$, then

$$\int_{t_0}^t g(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau=G(t)-G(t_0)$$

In your integral equation, $e^{-\lambda t}x(t)$ plays the role of $G$. From here it's just a matter of isolating $x(t)$.

$$\begin{align}
e^{-\lambda t}x(t)&=e^{-\lambda t_0}x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t e^{-\lambda \tau}f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau\\
x(t)&=e^{\lambda (t-t_0)}x(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t e^{\lambda(t-\tau)}f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's wonderful!